# The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock in ionic 3 ios build

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3, cocoapods

```
Run custom shell script cp check pods manifest.lock    
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I'm using **ionic 3** and I want to build my application in **ios** but it creates an issue mentioned above.

I tried

```
pod install,
pod update,
reinstall of cocoapods,
pod cache clean**,**cocoapods deintergrate**,**restart of my project, 
clean and build of my project
```

Nothing worked and I removed **libpods.a** files from build phase in every build of my project in Xcode,  and also I tried many solutions from various sites but till now i didn't get the solution

Comment: Please provide the full message error and the ionic command used in your build, including your xcode version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

- quit Xcode
- navigate to project folder
- delete `Pods` folder
- delete `Podfile.lock`
- call from command line `pod install`
- important: open the the project via `.xcworkspace` (and not via .xcodeproj)

If that doesn't work, make a build settings checks:

- in Navigator go to the root node
- in the editor on the right choose 'Build Settings'
- scroll down: there you should see the following entries:
  [image]
  PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH should show your project directory (where PODFILE resides, here you can enter `${SRCROOT}/.`, and for PODS_ROOT you can enter `${SRCROOT}/Pods`)

Correct the entries if necessary

Comment: Ok - I extended the answer a bit

Comment: I tried everything as you mentioned but finally, I solved this issue by without installing pod in my project directory now it's working like a charm!

Comment: you might have already installed pods right then how can you do without installing could you please elaborate what you did...Thank you

Comment: hi, I know it's late, but it will be a good help if you can tell how did you install pods into project directory?

Comment: @StephanSchlecht I'm having the same issue but it's not owrking for me.  And I don't have the PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH in xCode.  Any suggestions?